# Rmarkdown and Pandoc templates - specifying paths to assets

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I am attempting to create my own pandoc template for use with RStudio/Rmarkdown and HTML output. After some code snooping, google searches and trial/error I have a functional template that works as expected. I have included the template within an R package as well as my own custom function for calling `html_document()`.

However, I am unable to determine the appropriate way to specify/reference local assets (e.g. images) I would like included within my pandoc HTML template. I have tried specifying the path relative to the pandoc template with no luck. I'm surmising that I need to provide an absolute path and I can get that from `System.file()`. For assets such as css files that are specified within the header, I can handle that as part of my custom call to `html_document`. In this case, however, I'm trying to specify a path within the HTML body and not sure how to elegantly include that within the pandoc template.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: Workarounds I use: 1/ CSS rule `background-image: url('relative-path);` 2/ HTML include with base64 encoded image. JavaScript could also be used as a workaround (more painful).